# Intresting behavior with JQuery UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am working on a tool to have my employee's fill out their availability, but I seem to have run into an interesting bug. The form works by using a range slider and the employee can drag their start time and end time to the proper range that they will be available.

The bug I have is when you initially move the slider forward, it does not change on the first step, and when you try and go back to the minimum (or maximum) it will fall 30 min short (one step)

HTML:

```
<span id="montime" class="text_regular" style="font-size:24px;"></span><br><br>
<span class="text_regular"><b>Check if available</b></span>
<input type="checkbox" name="moncheck" <?php echo $monchecked; ?> /><br><br>
    <div id="monslide"></div>
    <input type="text" id="monraw" name="monraw"/>
    <input type="text" id="monobj" name="monobj"/>
```

JS:

http://pastebin.com/UnxJT4fe

Update:

I got it working in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cZxrb/10/

As you can see, it does not conform to the minimum/maximum that I have set for it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to work in fiddle too. It's like it's not loading the jQuery-UI.

Comment: It's funny: If the min (or max) is 30 minutes short, you can move the other one to correct it...

Comment: An interesting note: if you move the right slider left, and then back again, the furthest it will go is 9:30. But then if you adjust the left slider, it fixes it back to 10:00

Comment: The amount of bugs with this slider is driving me crazy :(

Comment: I think I found the [blog source](http://marcneuwirth.com/blog/2010/02/21/using-a-jquery-ui-slider-to-select-a-time-range/) of your code. He actually [did an update](http://marcneuwirth.com/blog/2011/05/22/revisiting-the-jquery-ui-time-slider/) on it saying there were lots of bugs and [released a plugin](https://github.com/marcneuwirth/jquery-ui-timeslider) to address all the issues

Comment: I should have seen this sooner, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*final solution below*

The Problem is that the `slide` event is called before the actual change.

You can use the `change` event, but this one will only be called if the slider is released.

```
$("#monslide").slider({
        range: true,
        values: [360, 1320],
        min: 360,
        max: 1320,
        step: 30,
        change: monSlideTime
    });
```

However, this will worsen usability... Using both also doesn't yield a nice feeling, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cZxrb/15/

**Update:**
Ok, I did a little research in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/). You should use the `ui` object to read values. `ui.value` returns the resulting value of the current slider move and `ui.values` provides both values before the move.

The check I used here might be implemented cleaner, but it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/cZxrb/21/

By the way, there was no bug in the slider code, I think their behaviour is intended like this... ;-)

Comment: Thank you for that information. This might be the solution I go with, but I am afraid it might confuse people. Any other suggestions or alternatives you could suggest?

Comment: Ok, I found the solution and updated the jsFiddle. Instead of reading from the html elements, you should use the `ui` object provided in the `slide` event handler.